# How do I reference the -s flag for javac in an ant script?

Tags: ant, javac, openjpa, metamodel

I am trying to compile the canonical metamodel classes for some JPA entities using an ant script.  I am using OpenJPA.  I would like the generated files to be located in a subdirectory which, according to the OpenJPA documentation, I can do by specifying the -s option for javac.  The way I am trying to do this right now is like this:

```
<compilerarg value="-s c:\buildfiles"/>
```

However, I keep getting an error that says:

```
javac: invalid flag: -s 
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

If I do:

```
<compilerarg value="-version"/>
```

it tells me that I am using 1.6.  And if I do:

```
<compilerarg value="-help"/>
```

it lists -s as a valid option.  Does anybody have any advice on what I can do to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *two* args in there, with a space between them.  You just need to separate them:

```
<compilerarg value="-s"/>
<compilerarg value="c:\buildfiles"/>
```

At the moment you're parsing the single arg "-s c:\buildfiles".  If you run

```
ant -verbose
```

you can verify this - you'll see something like:

```
  [javac] Compilation arguments:
    [javac] '-classpath'
    [javac] ''
    [javac] '-sourcepath'
    [javac] '/a/b/c'
    [javac] '-target'
    [javac] '1.5'
    [javac] '-g:none'
    [javac] '-s c:\buildfiles'    <-- here is the problem
    [javac] '-source'
    [javac] '1.5'
    [javac] 
    [javac] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
    [javac] not part of the command.
```